# How to enable publishing of ClickOnce applications?

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I have SKD project Net461. VS 2019. And I dont have options to publish ClickOnce like it look like in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-using-clickonce-folder?view=vs-2019

I was looking for a component in VS installer and I find only one: "Publishing with the ClickOnce application".

I have only this:

[image]

And I don't have a publish tab in Project Properties.

Comment: the link you provided is used for .net core app. You can refer to the link [ Deploy a .NET Framework desktop app using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-publish-a-clickonce-application-using-the-publish-wizard?view=vs-2019). For the problem, I suggest that you can update your vs to the latest version or use vs installer to repair your vs. If the problem still exists, you can report a problem in the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem).

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT I do not have these options at all for publication as in the link. From what I read, they didn't make ClickOnce installation possible for SDK projects at all. They only added this for Net 5.0 and Core 3.1, but I am unable to update projects due to lack of libraries. Tests workarounds and alternative libraries available. Maybe something will work.

Comment: What do you mean about SDK projects, is winform or console app?

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT WPF. I create project with framework  Core, and change TargetFrameworks to net461 to have SDK project.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT You can test it in a simple way as described above if you want. Make a project with the Net50 framework, try to publish it, and then change to Net461 and there is no such possibility.

Comment: Based on my test, I find the difference is that the sdk project doesn't have the tab clickonce. Is that your problem?

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT When I wrote this post I didn't know it yet, now I know, currently I'm looking for an alternative solution to replace ClickOnce. I left a post to possibly describe my solution if I manage to achieve something in this matter. I tested MageUI.exe, but it dont work, a lot of error and no solutions. Now I'm going to test the Squirrel, AutoUpdater.NET and NetSparkleUpdater libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Not through the IDE, but I was able to put ClickOnce in a WPF net48 project with new SDK style to run in an easy way when using `msbuild /t:publish`.

More info at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69583858/4386359